# equal size, equal-size or equally-sized?

Tags: phrase-choice, style, hyphens

What of the following is the most correct and best styled?:

> - There is a desert with two equal size water pools.
> - There is a desert with two equal-size water pools.
> - There is a desert with two equally-sized water pools.
> - There is a desert with two water pools of equal size.

Answer (score 4):

"equally-sized" (adv + adj) does not require a hyphen.

"equal size water pools" (adj + noun + noun + noun) needs a hyphen.

So that leaves us a choice between the second and fourth renderings.

I prefer the fourth one:

- . . Two [water] pools of equal size.

simply because it does not have three consecutive nouns.

(However, I put "water" in brackets, because I feel it is not needed.  Unless specified, a "pool" is assumed to be a pool of water—even in a desert!) If you take out "water", #2 sounds just as good as #4.

Comment: +1 for also addressing the stylistic aspect of the OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

COCA shows enough results for 'equal-sized' that serve as an adjective. So, in your case, it could be...

> There is a desert with two equal-sized water pools. 
>  We then found cutoff points within each category to form 3 nearly equal-sized groups (COCA).

**or**, another way to say this is the last option you quoted. Use 'of equal size' after the noun in concern.

> There is a desert with two water pools of equal size. 
>  Break the dough into 15 portions of equal size (COCA).

The words 'equal-size' is also possible but less frequently shown.

> Fetch the dough from the refrigerator and cut it into eight equal-size pieces (COCA)

Finally, 'equally-sized' is an improper use of those words. Don't use it.

'Equal size' without hyphen is also found. Again, less frequently used.

> By cutting between the uprights, I can get four equal size pieces of firewood (COCA)

So, to sum up:

> There is a desert with two equal size water pools -*less frequent* 
>  There is a desert with two equal-size water pools -*less frequent* 
>  There is a desert with two equally-sized water pools -*improper* 
>  There is a desert with two water pools of equal size -*proper (and preferred?)*. **And adding...**
>  There's a desert with two equal-sized water pools -*proper (and frequent?)*.

Comment: +1 for doing corpus research :-)  By the way, *equally sized* is okay, but without the hyphen.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather go with:

> There is a desert with two equal-**sized** water pools.[In place of 1st sentence]

OR

> There is a desert with two water pools (that are) equal **in** size. [In place of 4th sentence]

I'm not a native speaker, but I find above sentences correct. IMO, 'equally' cannot be used before size or sized.